# How to fix this in excel

Tags: excel, function

Hello I have these details in a single cell - 123 road,
1333, road 2, 234-  should be divided into three fixed columns (address 1,address 2 and post code)

I need address 1 (123 road) and ( 1333, road2) in address 2 and post code (2)

And there are some data like this 537 road 1, road 2, 27412
Which is gonna split perfectly into (address 1,address 2 and post code) when we do a text column.

But when I run it I need 1333, Cedar Bluff together in address 2 ( but when I do text to column it shows only 1333 and cedar bluff in the post code since it’s been divided by a (,)
But when i run the second one everything is fixed perfectly
How to deal this with this if there are 100 records

Comment: If there is only 100 then I would do a text to columns and then fix with manual work what didn't come out correct.

Answer (score 0):

This formula requires TEXTSPLIT function

```
=IF(COUNTA(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,",")))=3,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,",")),TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,",")),1,1)&"|"&INDEX(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,",")),1,2)&", "&INDEX(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,",")),1,3)&"|"&INDEX(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,",")),1,4),"|"))
```

[image]

Comment: It's already some time that I have troubles with the fact that `Split()` exists in VBA, but not in Excel itself. I assume `TextSplit()` function is an answer on that? I don't know about the question author, but I have Excel 365, version 2002 and I don't have this `TextSplit()` function.